# How can I keep Terminal always on top of other windows?

Tags: gnome, command-line, xorg

I want to keep `gnome-terminal` application on top of all the applications, even when it is unfocused. How can I do so?

Answer (score 15):

Right click on title bar, and choose "Always on Top".

[image]

Comment: And how do I set this to be the default behavior? I want the setting to persist.

Comment: @MarciCăşvan,
I don't know if it's possible to make this persistent. However, you might wanna open new question asking about that. Good luck!

Comment: Nice trick for Terminal but it doesn't work when the window doesn't have a regular titlebar (like a few popular browsers...)