# Terminal command to keep window on top

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, window

I have created a Pomodoro Timer which runs in a seperate terminal window. I want this timer to always remain on top of other windows.

While searching for an answer, I found this: [How can I keep Terminal always on top of other windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235609/how-can-i-keep-terminal-always-on-top-of-other-windows).

But, this would mean that whenever I run my script, I'll have to manually right click the title bar and select "Always on top".

I was wondering if there is a temporary terminal command for that (which I can add to my code), so that it can keep the particular terminal window on top. (and the setting resets on closing the terminal, i.e. it is not permanent.)

Comment: `wmctrl -i -r <window id> -b add,above` or `wmctrl -r "window name" -b add,above`

Comment: How to get the Window ID, I have seen `xwininfo -display :0` but it requires the user to manually select the window. @kenn

Comment: You can use window name in quotes as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 configure vlc always on top](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081712/ubuntu-18-04-configure-vlc-always-on-top)

Comment: No @pomsky, I don't want the effect to be permanent rather, I want it to stay only for the particular session.

Comment: @kenn On using window name, I get an error: `Cannot convert argument to number`...

Comment: @aakash Ah, I see, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: don't add the `-i` switch if you use window name: `wmctrl -r "window name" -b add,above`

Comment: Not working (nothing happens), plus, if I have multiple terminals open, all of them will have the same window name...@kenn

Comment: `wmctrl -l` will list window ids

Comment: This may help to give the terminal a unique name then raise it based on title: https://askubuntu.com/questions/516223/open-terminal-in-always-on-top-mode-on-startup

Answer (score 2):

The answer is :

1. Install wmctrl
2. Open a terminal and type wmctrl -l. You will see a list of windows and processes.
3. Type : wmctrl -i -r $windowId -b add,above
   (please replace $windowId by the window id of step 2)

Thanks to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233113/what-would-be-the-command-line-equivalent-of-always-on-top-option-on-windows)